# I have this boilerplate setup of a React App from a Udemy course, I have installed the dependencies, but when I am trying to run it, it has errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, webpack, babeljs

The Github link to the source code: https://github.com/bhatvikrant/react_boilerplate_v1

Do the following:

1. Clone the repo
2. npm install
3. yarn run dev-server

after doing these 3 steps I am encountering the following error:

```
yarn run v1.19.1
$ webpack-dev-server
Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
webpack output is served from /
Content not from webpack is served from /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/public
Hash: ead274a634f7a645548e
Version: webpack 3.1.0
Time: 1998ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
bundle.js  2.93 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
  [25] ./node_modules/react/lib/React.js 5.08 kB {0} [built]
 [115] ./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js 8.7 kB {0} [built]
 [116] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
 [117] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 5.59 kB {0} [built]
 [118] ./node_modules/url/url.js 23.3 kB {0} [built]
 [119] ./node_modules/node-libs-browser/node_modules/punycode/punycode.js 14.7 kB {0} [built]
 [124] ./node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
 [126] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 856 bytes {0} [built]
 [158] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.6 kB {0} [built]
 [163] (webpack)/hot/emitter.js 77 bytes {0} [built]
 [165] ./src/app.js 492 bytes {0} [built]
 [166] ./node_modules/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
 [185] ./node_modules/react-dom/index.js 59 bytes {0} [built]
 [271] ./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css 1.05 kB {0} [built]
 [274] ./src/styles/styles.scss 1.15 kB {0} [built]
    + 261 hidden modules

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
 @ ./node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css 4:14-94
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js

ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/styles/styles.scss
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
Require stack:
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/lib/Server.js
- /Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:794:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:687:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/VIKRANT/Desktop/boilerplate-v1/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
 @ ./src/styles/styles.scss 4:14-124
 @ ./src/app.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/app.js
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

How to rectify the errors and run the code properly?

I have made the webpack.config.js file and also the .babelrc file, still I am unable to understand where I am going wrong.

Error after running both the node-sass commands:

```
> node-sass@4.13.0 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/bin/node',
gyp verb cli   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
gyp verb cli ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.13.0 | darwin | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python2 /usr/bin/python2
gyp verb check python version `/usr/bin/python2 -c "import sys; print "2.7.16
gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"` returned: %j
gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 12.13.0
gyp verb command install [ '12.13.0' ]
gyp verb install input version string "12.13.0"
gyp verb install installing version: 12.13.0
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version is already installed, need to check "installVersion"
gyp verb got "installVersion" 9
gyp verb needs "installVersion" 9
gyp verb install version is good
gyp verb get node dir target node version installed: 12.13.0
gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.0.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
Build failed with error code: 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.13.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.13.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/VIKRANT/.npm/_logs/2019-10-29T09_54_06_016Z-debug.log
```

Comment: do ```npm i node-sass --save-dev```  in you shell

Comment: you are using scss loader , it uses node-sass to parse those scss files

Comment: Even I thought so but it's a part of [dependencies - Line 21](https://github.com/bhatvikrant/react_boilerplate_v1/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: but the error clearly says, it might be something like, there may be a persmission error with node-sass that's why it aint installed

Comment: can you do ```npm i node-sass --save-dev --unsafe-perm``` and also ```npm i node-sass -g```

Comment: @Raju correct, I am running that command right now, lets see

Comment: run both commands then tell me

Comment: @Raju I have run both the commands, I am still getting errors

Comment: @Raju I have updated the errors in my question

Comment: hey you see this.. ```Error: EACCES: permission denied``` it means you must run command with admin right , it;s not able to  install node-sass in your file system , use sudo if on ubuntu , other wise in windows "run as admin"

Comment: @Raju oh Sorry, I have run it as administrator and updated the errors again, Please check

Comment: hmm, you in ubuntu ?

Comment: @Raju I am on MacOS

Comment: try this ```sudo rm -rf node_modules && npm rebuild node-sass && npm i```  also have a look here https://github.com/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#which-node-runtime-am-i-using

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: @Raju after running sudo rm -rf node_modules && npm rebuild node-sass && npm i, still the same error

Comment: can you run ```sudo npm i node-sass --save-dev --unsafe-perm```  i know we shouldn;t allow sudo , but for the sake of it , still, i have also been this mess before on linux and using this command with sudo solved for me on linux... if doesn't solve then give this a try: 
https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: @Raju Heyyy! Thanks Mate it worked finally!!, REALLY Appreciate the help man!

Comment: haha , but in your free time i would suggest instead of using sudo , do read this one:https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Comment: Correct, I ll Backup my pc and then do it.